# How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to see the `maxLength` of an `EditText` at run time to be able to make a text display decision.
Is that possible?

Here is a description of what I wan't to do.

I have a ListView with many rows and each row have an EditText and a TextView.
I've made a subclass of ArrayAdapter to be able to feed the String that I want to place in the EditText of each row.
I have set `android:maxLength="12"` in the XML file.
I want to display a number in that EditText field, but if the number I want to display has more than `android:maxLength="12"` I want to display an "error message" instead.

And I would prefer not to hard code that 12 in my subclass of ArrayAdapter.

There is probably a simple solution, but I haven't found it yet.
(android first time...)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Only limited parameters have their getters, so I don't think you can read it .

So write length (Say 12) in values folder and use it in xml layout and arrayAdapter . 
Now its not hard-coded .

***1)Create integer.xml in values ****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="integer" name="max_length">12</item>
</resources>
```

**2)In layout**

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="@integer/max_length"
    />
```

**3) in ArrayAdapter :**

```
int maxLength = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.max_length);
```

Comment: I had the feeling it would need to come down to that... option. I was hoping to find a more dynamic way.

Comment: i usually go through this way,wherever its difficult to retrieve the value back .

Answer (score 39):

This should work:

> ```
> editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(12) });
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it's putting me on the right track, but how do I get that 12 back. My tries are half way there but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 14):

From api 21 you can do it like that:

```
for (InputFilter filter : mEditText.getFilters()) {
        if (filter instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
            ((InputFilter.LengthFilter) filter).getMax());
        }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

extend the edit text and retrieve the value from the attributeset in the constructor.

public class MyEditText extends EditText {

```
public static final String XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
private int mMaxLength;

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mMaxLength = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID, "maxLength", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin one line solution - returns max length or null if not set

```
view.filters.filterIsInstance<InputFilter.LengthFilter>().firstOrNull()?.max
```

As extension:

```
val TextView.maxLength: Int?
    get() = filters.filterIsInstance<InputFilter.LengthFilter>().firstOrNull()?.max
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Field value **using the Reflection API**.

### Why You Shouldn't Do It

---

Just about everyone would advocate against it (including me) because:

- It's slow
- It's **implementation-dependant**
- It's not intended to be accessed (obviously)

As of now, looking at the source code (Android API 19), the implementation depends on an
`InputFilter.LengthFilter` which is set in the constructor as:

```
if (maxlength >= 0) {
    setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxlength) });
} else {
    setFilters(NO_FILTERS);
}
```

where `maxLength` is the Integer you're interested in finding, parsed from the xml attribute (`android:maxLength="@integer/max_length"`).
This `InputFilter.LengthFilter` has only one field (`private int mMax`) and no accessor method.

### How It Can Be Done

---

- Declare a static method in a relevant utility class accepting a `TextView` and returning an `int`.
- Iterate over each `InputFilter` set on the `TextView` and find one belonging to the `InputFilter.LengthFilter` implementation.
- Access, get and return the mMax field's value using Reflection.

This would give you something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// [...]

public static int getMaxLengthForTextView(TextView textView)
{
    int maxLength = -1;

    for (InputFilter filter : textView.getFilters()) {
        if (filter instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
            try {
                Field maxLengthField = filter.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMax");
                maxLengthField.setAccessible(true);

                if (maxLengthField.isAccessible()) {
                    maxLength = maxLengthField.getInt(filter);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.w(filter.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.w(filter.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Log.w(filter.getClass().getName(), e);
            } // if an Exception is thrown, Log it and return -1
        }
    }

return maxLength;
}
```

As mentioned earlier, this will break if the implementation that sets the maximum length of the `TextView` changes. You will be notified of this change when the method starts throwing. Even then, the method still returns -1, which you should be handling as *unlimited length*.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of complicated, but I don't know of any other approach. I hope it works (not tested):

```
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.theLayout);
String namespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
int maxLength = parser.getAttributeIntValue(namespace, "maxLength", 12);
```

Comment: I get back the default value of the method call and not the actual one.