# Finding number of characters in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a `textview` in the whole layout. I want to know how many characters can be shown on that `textview`. I know the width and height of `textview` and font size also now I just want to know the number of characters that can show this `textview`. I tried `textview.getText().toString().length()` but it returns total number of characters which I passed it through the string but it display less.

Comment: Unless you are using a _fixed_ font, the variable widths and kerning mean that there is no definitive answer

Comment: If i am using fixed font what would be no of characters..??

Answer (score 2):

While K-ballo's point about fixed-width (and variable-width) fonts is spot on, if you want to know how many characters *of a particular string* can fit in a `TextView`, you might be able to check it using something like [`Paint.getTextWidths`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextWidths%28java.lang.String,%20float%5B%5D%29). Just make sure to set the proper styles/font face before calling it.

Answer (score 1):

So I though there would be a nice solution to this like text.getMaxLength()

But I guess there is not. You'll have to play with some xml that will set the value for you so you know what it is. Check out the sample code in this post

[How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code)

Comment: That's just imposing a fixed max length and then reading it dynamically. It doesn't answer how many characters fit in the `TextView`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about your question. The max length tells your exactly how many characters fit into a textView

Comment: No, max length tells you how many characters you're limiting the `TextView` to. You can set it to whatever you like resulting in strings that would be wider than the `TextView` when rendered. You could for example set it to 10,000 even when the `TextView` has a width of 10px and font size of 100px in which case most likely not even a single whole "A" character would fit let alone 10,000.