# Set error if the user tries to type after limit is reached in Android edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried via `TextWatcher`'s `afterTextChanged`. All I want is display a toast message or set error on `EditText` if the user tries to insert characters after the limit is reached. I think it is possible. But don't know how to achieve this.

### Update

My EditText coding is

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
```

Here if the user tries to enter more than 10 digit I want to display a toast or want to set error.

### Update

```
 editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (editText1.getText().length() >= 10)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: The limit being the size of `maxLength`?

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the maxLength of your `editText` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code). Then implement a keyListener.

```
 int maxLength = //getMaxLenght here;
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().length()>= maxLength) {
                //Show toast here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This should work. Try to print `maxLength` attribute and `editText.getText().toString().length()` before the if statement and tell me what it prints when you reach the limit.

Comment: without if condition also nothing happened.

Comment: Is something printed when you type on your EditText ?

Comment: No friend.. Nothing printed

Comment: I saw that you have set the listener on editText2 instead of editText1 maybe your filling the wrong editText. Could you try to print something just before the if statement please ?

Comment: I got it friend. Thank you so much. Before I use both `addTextChangedListener` and `setOnKeyListener` separately. That is the problem. Now I was wrote `setOnKeyListener` to inside the `addTextChangedListener`. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

On key listener doesn't work on Soft Input Keyboard..
From the Android reference at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

View.OnKeyListener

Class Overview Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener.

So that means that TextWatcher is only your friend with editboxes and keyboard Inputs..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the maximum length of the EditText you could use **`EditText.setError(String errorMsg)`** like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if (charSequence.toString().length() >= maxLength) {
            // show toast / error here
            String limitReached = "Maximum limit of characters reached!";
            editText.setError(limitReached);
        } else {
            // clear error
            editText.setError(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

It will look something like this. When that EditText is not in focus, the error message is not shown, but the error icon stays visible. You may use `EditText.getError()` to check if there is an error currently set on the EditText.

[image: example of EditText.setError() appearance]

This may be more than you are asking, but **if you have an EditText with a dynamic character limit,** I'd recommend hanging onto that value somewhere in the `maxLength` variable. (For example, the security code for a payment card varies based on card type)

However, you ***can*** do the following to programmatically check what the XML value of `android:maxLength` is currently set to:

```
    private int getEditTextCharacterLimit(EditText editText) {
        int defaultMaxLength = 5; // default value

        InputFilter[] filters = editText.getFilters();
        if (filters != null && filters[0] != null && filters[0] instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
            return ((InputFilter.LengthFilter) filters[0]).getMax();
        } else {
            return defaultMaxLength;
        }
    }
```

[Here's how you would dynamically change the EditText's character limit programmatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461824/how-to-programmatically-set-maxlength-in-android-textview/31074943)

Answer (score 0):

This may be more than you are asking, but if you have an EditText with a dynamic character limit, I'd recommend hanging onto that value somewhere in the maxLength variable. (For example, the security code for a payment card varies based on card type)

Answer (score 0):

```
 val maxLength = 20
        edtPassword.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (s.length > maxLength) {
                    s.delete(maxLength, s.length)
                    errorPassword.value = getLocalizationString(
                        R.string.passwordMaxLengthErrorMessage,
                        viewModel.maxPasswordLength
                    )
                }
            }
        })
```

I was dealing with the same issue and this is worked fine in my code (Kotlin)