# getMaxLenght of Edittext In Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to get MaxLength of Edittext in Android ?

It's already set by:

```
android:maxLength="6
```

OR

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(12) });
```

Comment: I would get the filters list, test if one of these is an instance of InputFilter.LengthFilter, then cast it, and `getMax` on it.

Answer (score 1):

the function getMax is added in API level 21, for older version use this [How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code)