# How to get maxLength of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I set the max length of `EditText` by writing the following in XML file

```
android:maxLength="16"
```

I want to get this length programmatically (inside `TextWatcher`).
I got one answer using [How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code) link, however, it is not what I want because it does not work when the maxLength is changed in runtime.

How can I get the length of EditText programmatically? (MinSDKVersion is 14)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code)

Comment: Do you want to get the maxLength or the current length?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I mentioned about the link you said. What if I change maxLength in runtime? In this case this answer does not work for me

Comment: @TDG I want maxLength

Comment: @tm13 that is not an answer, that is a question. It has multiple answers, last of which will work. Make sure you have checked all of them

Answer (score 1):

create integer in `integers.xml` and get set that value in `EditText` like this,

> In `integers.xml`

```
<item name="max_char">16<item>
```

> set in `EditText` like this

```
android:maxLength="@integer/max_char"
```

> get integer in `Javafile` like this

```
int maxChar = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.max_char);
```