# getting text length limit of current input field - Android Input Method

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am developing a soft keyboard. I want to notify user the maximum text length reached.
Is there any way to get maximum text length allowed by current input field in which user is typing ?

`getCurrentInputEditorInfo()` returns `EditorInfo` object which contain many details including `fieldName`, `fieldType`, `hintText`, etc
But there is no field to get text length limit detail.

The application programmer can set field length limit for his `EditText` using following line.

```
android:maxLength="15"
```

I am talking about retrieving this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code)

Comment: have you tried TextWatcher()?

Answer (score 0):

One of the items you can get from the EditorInfo object is `fieldId`. You can use that with `findViewById` to get the actual EditText and from that get the length using one of the techniques detailed in [How to Get EditText maxLength setting in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code).