# Android EditText error is reset after maxLength is reached

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `setError()` and use the `maxLength` attribute on an EditText view, but after maxLength is reached and the user continues to type the error disappears. What is the proper place to call `setError()`, so that it doesn't get removed in this situation?

XML code

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:maxLength="5"/>
```

Java Code

```
EditText myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(myEditText));
```

Test TextWatcher that always sets error message.

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText view;
    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {view = editText;}
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        view.setError("setError worked");
    }
}
```

My testing device: Android 8.1 and software keyboard

Comment: So your idea is you want to show the error msg when the user exceeds the maxlemgth limit ?

Comment: public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {this.view = editText;} add this.view and let me know if that solved your error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using a `InputFilter` in addition to a `TextWatcher`.

Because [there isn't an easy way to access the `maxLength` attribute in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code), I created an integer resource for it. This way the max length can be managed in one stop.

XML for EditText view

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:maxLength="@integer/myMaxLength"/>
```

XML for integer resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="myMaxLength">5</integer>
</resources>
```

Java setting up the `InputFilter`. The new filter is added to the EditText view's current filters.

```
final EditText myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(myEditText));
final int myMaxLength = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.myMaxLength);
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (myEditText.getText().length() >= myMaxLength) {
            myEditText.setError("setError worked (InputFilter)");
        }
        return null;
    }
};
InputFilter[] oldFilters = myEditText.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[oldFilters.length+1];
System.arraycopy(oldFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, oldFilters.length);
newFilters[newFilters.length-1] = filter;
myEditText.setFilters(newFilters);
```

Java for the `TextWatcher`

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText view;
    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {view = editText;}
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {view.setError("Error Message");}
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {view.setError("Error Message");}
    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        view.setError("setError worked (TextWatcher)");
    }
}
```